# Reading File to byte[] with fixed buffer size generates duplicate output

Tags: java, io

if I read via

```
package net.example;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
    int rc = in.read(buffer);
    while (rc != -1) {
        System.out.print(new String(buffer));
        rc = in.read(buffer);
    }
}
}
```

a textfile, the it doesn't put out the correct content. The output is bigger than the input.

Example: http://pastebin.com/r5uGfYgD

I know it is because of the buffer size. But how can i tell it to stop reading after the file ends?

Edit:

Now it works, here to full source. Thanks a lot! If somebody has some improvments: Tell me!

```
package net.example;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import fr.cryptohash.Digest;
import fr.cryptohash.MD5;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Digest dig = new MD5();
    byte[] srcBuffer = new byte[102400];
    byte[] buffer = null;

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("text.txt");

    int rc = -1;
    while ((rc = in.read(srcBuffer)) != -1) {
        buffer = new byte[rc];

        System.arraycopy(srcBuffer, 0, buffer, 0, rc);
        dig.update(buffer);
    }
    System.out.println(toHex(dig.digest()));
}

private static String toHex(byte[] hash) {
    char[] HEX_CHARS = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(hash.length * 2);
    for (byte b : hash) {
        sb.append(HEX_CHARS[(b & 0xF0) >> 4]);
        sb.append(HEX_CHARS[b & 0x0F]);
    }
    String hex = sb.toString();

    return hex;
}
}
```

Comment: One possible improvement is that if rc == srcBuffer.length, you can avoid making the copy of the array and just use srcBuffer directly.  This could make it significantly faster, as the allocation and copy takes quite a lot of time, and for a large file rc will equal srcBuffer.length many times before (in the final iteration) it comes out short.

Comment: @Jules Thanks! It saves about 20 seconds on a 100GB file :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using [String(bytes[], offset, length)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) constructor?

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
int rc = -1;
while ((rc = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    System.out.print(new String(buffer, 0, rc));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great! But currently I need the pure byte[] is there a way to truncate the byte[] it self? It could do it with `new String(buffer, 0, rc).getBytes()` but i'm not sure if this is very efficent :(

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible without `rc`. Maybe some other answers will have more info.

Comment: @user2765509 Anyway where do you need to use result of `getBytes()`? If you want it as some argument in standard Java method then there should be also version where you can pass `rc`, like every OutputStream has `write(b, off, len)` method.

Comment: I need it to generate a hash of it. Via sphlib (http://www.saphir2.com/sphlib/). I need to use it because if the file is too large. I run out of memory. It's update method only accepts a byte Array

Comment: you can copy one byte[] to another with System.arrayCopy(), but anyway you should use rc in your code

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read the file contents to a byte[], you can use a ByteArrayOutputStream or using commons io which has a "read to byte[]" util method.